# espidf COMPONENT_DIR

Tags: cmake, esp-idf

I'm trying to compile a simple Hello_world example using the Smooth component (https://github.com/PerMalmberg/Smooth), and get error: **include could not find load file:
   ../lib/compiler_options.cmake**.
It seems that COMPONENT_DIR is not set, but I'm not aware whether/where to set this, or where this should have been set.

I've been staring at this too long, and am not finding the (apparently) obvious problem. Anyone any thoughts?

**ERROR**

```
Note: You are using Python 3.8.0. Python 3 support is new, please report any problems you encounter. Search for 'Setting
 the Python Interpreter' in the ESP-IDF docs if you want to use Python 2.7.
Checking Python dependencies...
Python requirements from C:\Esp32_tools\esp-idf-v3.3\requirements.txt are satisfied.
Running cmake in directory C:\Temp\esp\testCPP\build
Executing "cmake -G Ninja -DPYTHON_DEPS_CHECKED=1 -DESP_PLATFORM=1 --warn-uninitialized C:\Temp\esp\testCPP"...
Warn about uninitialized values.
-- Building for target esp32
-- ccache will be used for faster builds

CMake Error at C:/Temp/esp/testCPP/externals/smooth/smooth_component/CMakeLists.txt:21 (include):
  include could not find load file:
   ../lib/compiler_options.cmake

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Esp32_tools/esp-idf-v3.3/tools/cmake/scripts/expand_requirements.cmake:107 (include)
  C:/Esp32_tools/esp-idf-v3.3/tools/cmake/scripts/expand_requirements.cmake:217 (expand_component_requirements)`


CMake Error at C:/Esp32_tools/esp-idf-v3.3/CMakeLists.txt:39 (message):
  Failed to expand component requirements
```

**VERSION**

```
C:\Temp\esp\testCPP>cmake --version
cmake version 3.13.4

CMake suite maintained and supported by Kitware (kitware.com/cmake).
```

**CMakeLists.txt**

````
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

if(${ESP_PLATFORM})
include($ENV{IDF_PATH}/tools/cmake/project.cmake)

# Include Smooth as a component
set(EXTRA_COMPONENT_DIRS
         externals/smooth/smooth_component)

project(name_of_your_project)
else()
    # Empty project when not building for ESP (i.e. when loading the project into an IDE with already configured tool chains for native Linux)
endif()```
````

Answer (score 0):

> CMake Error at C:/Esp32_tools/esp-idf-v3.3/CMakeLists.txt:39 (message):
>     Failed to expand component requirements

You are missing this line in CMakeLists.txt

https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/blob/master/examples/get-started/hello_world/CMakeLists.txt#L3

Comment: Thanks for helping me out, I will attempt this later today. On a side note, how could I have figured this out myself? I looked at log files, verbose output, etc, but must have missed something somewhere. Alternatively, is there another way to “debug” these make files?